# Using custom elements created by polymer or any other library

Tags: web-component

After I have created custom element   with polymer library do I have to add any other library than polyfill in my website to get it work with modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You'll need to add the [webcomponents polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) library to make your custom element work.

In the  of your main (*index.html*) file:

```
<script src="path/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```